# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - Running multiple things paralellel but skip "branch" if earlier failure occured

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, pipeline, declarative

I wanna build one Jenkins pipeline that builds and runs tests on multiple versions of a program (e.g. Different databases)
But when any step fails, I want to skip the following steps only for that "branch" so to speak..

This is my example Code where Stage 1 is run first, with possible parallel steps (1.a, 1.b). The code does not work and is only some sort of example of how I would like it to work:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        stageOneFailed = "false"
        stageTwoFailed = "false"
    }
    
    
    stages {
        stage ("Stage 1") {
            parallel {
                stage("Stage 1.a") {
                    // Something like this maybe?
                    steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            // Do stuff here..
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        unsuccessful {
                            // When stage did not succeed..
                            // Set stageOneFailed = "true"
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                stage("Stage 1.b") {
                    // Do Stuff..
                    // If Stage 1.b fails, set stageTwoFailed="true"
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Stage 2") {
            parallel {
                // Only run stages if earlier steps didn't fail
                stage("Stage 2.a") {
                    when {
                        environment(name: "stageOneFailed", value: "false")
                    }
                    steps {
                        // Do stuff..
                        // If Stage 2.a fails, set stageOneFailed="true"
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 2.b") {
                    when {
                        environment(name: "stageTwoFailed", value: "false")
                    }
                    steps {
                        // Do stuff..
                        // If Stage 2.b fails, set stageTwoFailed="true"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // stage()
    }
}
```

Can anyone give any advice on how to do this the proper way?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Changed code example. The example runs now!

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        stageOneFailed = "false"
        stageTwoFailed = "false"
    }
    
    
    stages {
        stage ("Stage 1") {
            parallel {
                stage("Stage 1.a") {
                    steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            bat "ech Stage 1.a" // Should fail because ech is no valid command
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure  {
                            script {
                                env.stageOneFailed = "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                stage("Stage 1.b") {
                    steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            bat "echo Stage 1.b" // Should not fail
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure  {
                            script {
                                env.stageTwoFailed = "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Stage 2") {
            parallel {
                // Only run stages if earlier steps didn't fail
                stage("Stage 2.a") {
                    when {
                        environment(name: "stageOneFailed", value: "false")
                    }
                    steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            bat "echo Stage 2.a"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure  {
                            script {
                                env.stageOneFailed = "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 2.b") {
                    when {
                        environment(name: "stageTwoFailed", value: "false")
                    }
                    steps {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            bat "echo Stage 2.b"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        failure  {
                            script {
                                env.stageTwoFailed = "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when running the example, the Stage 1.a fails but Stage 2.a is still run, maybe anyone could help out here..

EDIT: I added output to see, what value stageNFailed is set to. Even after calling env.stageOneFailed, when going into next stage, it takes the old value false..

My assumption is, that when calling script env.stageNFailed = "true", the value is only set temporarily for that stage..

Answer (score 0):

The example you have used is a perfectly acceptable way to do it. You have introduced 2 env variables that get used to determine if the previous step failed. You have used `catchError` to ensure that the pipeline doesn't fail when the stage fails. You have to use `catchError` in every stage to prevent the pipeline from failing (but I guess you already know that). In the `post` part of the stage, you have set the appropriate env variable to true, which is also correct.

```
post {
    failure {
        script {
            env.stageOneFailed = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then when the next relevant stage starts, you have used the `when` condition to check if the stage should be run (you could also do something like this):

```
when {
    expression { stageOneFailed == false }
}
```

So basically you have done everything right.

Comment: This solution does not work for me..
When setting the env.stageOneFailed inside the script stuff, it is only set locally to this value.. in the next stage, it is the default from before..